# Post 1 million object to Mongo DB without running out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For the sake of simplicity, I've used a for loop here to create an array of 1 million objects.

I'd like to post each object in the array to mongo db.

I keep running out on memory.

I know I can increase the memory allocation, but that isn't the solution I want. I don't want to use the bulk method of mongo, either, for reasons beyond the scope of this example.

I'm aware that there must be some method of posting these objects which means that memory is released at each iteration (garbage collected?) - can anyone tell me what it is?

Thanks!

Current code here for reference (which causes allocation error):

```
var results = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 1000001; i++){

  results.push({"num":i});

}

async = require("async");
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://root@localhost:27017/results';

MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {

  var collection = db.collection('results');

  // 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
  async.each(results,
    // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
    function(item, callback){
      // Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
      collection.insert(item, function (err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(item);
        callback();
      });
    },
    // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
    function(err){
      // All tasks are done now
      db.close();
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async.each()` runs the inserts in parallel, so it basically starts 1000000 concurrent insert operations.

You may want to limit that to, say, 100, by using [`async.eachLimit()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [bulk operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/) if you want to optimize the insertions since it also reduces the network usage back and forth. Also storing huge arrays especially if they are just getting computed would be eating too much of memory.

```
var bulk = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 1, i = 0;
var bulkSize = 1000;

var generator = function (mx) {
    if(i < mx){
        return {num: i++}
    }
    return null;
}

var run = function () {
    doc = generator();
    if(doc) {
        bulk.insert(doc)
    }
    if(doc == null || count % bulkSize == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function (err, res) {
            if(err) {} // do something
            if(doc == null) {
                db.close
            }
            run();
        })
    }  
}
run()
```

Here, no big arrays are stored at any step of your program. Only while the bulk array is created you would be storing it. That too is flushed to MongoDB once it reached the `bulkSize`

Comment: Thanks, this is something further that I need to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Use setImmediate to prevent out of memory error

```
var results = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 1000001; i++){
  results.push({"num":i});
}



run(0, results.length, results, function(err){
    // do stg
});

function run(done, todo, results, callback)
{
    if(++done >= todo)
    {
        // return callback if all done
        return callback(null);
   }
    else
    {
        // save one using index
        //collection.insert(results[done], function(err, res){

       // OR save one and remove it from results
       collection.insert(results.splice(0,1),
            if(err)
                return callback(err);
            else
            {
                // use setImmediate to recall run while releasing stack
                return setImmediate(run, ++done, todo, results, callback);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I came across this when trying to do something similar. I kept running out of memory while trying to insert about 4 million documents. The solution for me was to dump all of the data to a JSON file, example:

##### users.json

```js
{ "name", "John", "city": "San Francisco" }
{ "name", "Jane", "city": "New York" }
```

I then used `mongoimport` to import the file into mongo:

```
mongoimport -u root --authenticationDatabase admin --host="localhost:27017" --db="my_db" --collection="Users" --numInsertionWorkers 4 --file="users.json"
```

`mongoimport` managed the memory and had a nice output display (see below). For 4 million documents, it took less than 2 minutes and only used 900 MB of RAM.

```
2022-06-21T17:46:46.711+0000    [........................] my_db.Users  30.9MB/903MB (3.4%)
2022-06-21T17:46:49.714+0000    [#.......................] my_db.Users  62.2MB/903MB (6.9%)
2022-06-21T17:46:52.711+0000    [##......................] my_db.Users  93.3MB/903MB (10.3%)
2022-06-21T17:46:55.711+0000    [###.....................] my_db.Users  124MB/903MB (13.7%)
2022-06-21T17:46:58.718+0000    [####....................] my_db.Users  155MB/903MB (17.2%)
2022-06-21T17:47:01.711+0000    [####....................] my_db.Users  186MB/903MB (20.6%)
2022-06-21T17:47:04.712+0000    [#####...................] my_db.Users  217MB/903MB (24.0%)
2022-06-21T17:47:07.716+0000    [######..................] my_db.Users  248MB/903MB (27.5%)
2022-06-21T17:47:10.711+0000    [#######.................] my_db.Users  279MB/903MB (30.8%)
2022-06-21T17:47:13.712+0000    [########................] my_db.Users  310MB/903MB (34.3%)
2022-06-21T17:47:16.712+0000    [#########...............] my_db.Users  341MB/903MB (37.7%)
2022-06-21T17:47:19.713+0000    [#########...............] my_db.Users  371MB/903MB (41.0%)
2022-06-21T17:47:22.717+0000    [##########..............] my_db.Users  401MB/903MB (44.4%)
2022-06-21T17:47:25.712+0000    [###########.............] my_db.Users  432MB/903MB (47.9%)
2022-06-21T17:47:28.711+0000    [############............] my_db.Users  464MB/903MB (51.4%)
2022-06-21T17:47:31.712+0000    [#############...........] my_db.Users  495MB/903MB (54.8%)
2022-06-21T17:47:34.713+0000    [#############...........] my_db.Users  526MB/903MB (58.3%)
2022-06-21T17:47:37.711+0000    [##############..........] my_db.Users  557MB/903MB (61.7%)
2022-06-21T17:47:40.713+0000    [###############.........] my_db.Users  588MB/903MB (65.1%)
2022-06-21T17:47:43.712+0000    [################........] my_db.Users  619MB/903MB (68.6%)
2022-06-21T17:47:46.711+0000    [#################.......] my_db.Users  650MB/903MB (71.9%)
2022-06-21T17:47:49.713+0000    [##################......] my_db.Users  680MB/903MB (75.3%)
2022-06-21T17:47:52.711+0000    [##################......] my_db.Users  712MB/903MB (78.8%)
2022-06-21T17:47:55.711+0000    [###################.....] my_db.Users  742MB/903MB (82.2%)
2022-06-21T17:47:58.717+0000    [####################....] my_db.Users  766MB/903MB (84.8%)
2022-06-21T17:48:01.715+0000    [####################....] my_db.Users  783MB/903MB (86.7%)
2022-06-21T17:48:04.712+0000    [#####################...] my_db.Users  810MB/903MB (89.7%)
2022-06-21T17:48:07.720+0000    [######################..] my_db.Users  840MB/903MB (93.0%)
2022-06-21T17:48:10.711+0000    [#######################.] my_db.Users  870MB/903MB (96.3%)
2022-06-21T17:48:13.712+0000    [#######################.] my_db.Users  899MB/903MB (99.6%)
2022-06-21T17:48:14.124+0000    [########################] my_db.Users  903MB/903MB (100.0%)
2022-06-21T17:48:14.124+0000    imported 4027382 documents
```